# Changing background colour on dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently in the process of making a navigation bar for a website using bootstrap. Everything seems to be working as expected. However on the menu I have a `li` which then displays a dropdown. This is where the problem comes in. When I click on the `li` the background seems to change to black and I can't figure out where that's coming from.

[image]

My markup looks as follows:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" runat="server">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" runat="server">
            <li>
                <a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a runat="server" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Training Group<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want so when I the back ground stays white. I've tried

```
.navbar> li.dropdown.active.open > a { background-color: #fff; }
```

But it doesn't seem to change the background colour. Can someone shed some light on where I'm going wrong please.

Thanks in advance for your help and support

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGGmRL)

Comment: try `.navbar li.dropdown.active.open a { background-color: #fff; }`

Comment: use `.navbar li.dropdown.active.open a { background-color: #fff !important; }`. If that does not work, please build a JSFiddle and I'll help you further

Comment: @TamilSelvan Still the same

Comment: Can you post the `css` for `dropdown-toggle`? What does inspect element on said menu item say? Can you see any `#000`?

Comment: @chriz I haven't got written any `css` for `dropdown-toggle` yet

Comment: @pablito.aven I've updated my markup by including the exact structure

Comment: did you try what we told you? If it stil does not work, consider building a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing the problem.

Comment: @pablito.aven I've tried what you guys suggested and it's still the same issue. I've created a code pen and updated it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment (by Tamil Selvan) may work for you (assuming the rule is specific enough), but it'd probably help if you knew why your original code fails: the reason is that `>` after `.navbar`. That `>` is a direct-child selector and the `li`s are not direct children of `.navbar`.

UPDATE: author posted a Pen and it became more clear he wasn't targeting the dropdown-menu at all, it was about the triggering element, so here's what helped:

> Looks like the CSS responsible for the black background color on the
>   LI that you click to reveal the dropdown is:
>
> .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
>   .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover.navbar-inverse

Comment: I've updated my markup to the exact structure I have can you please kindly tell me how would I change my `css`

Comment: Because of the way CSS specificity works, it's not possible to give you a guaranteed working answer based on the markup alone. One would have to know what CSS is already inherited by the intended element.

Comment: I've created a code pen with the current css I have

Comment: Looks like the CSS responsible for the black background color on the LI that you click to reveal the dropdown is:

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover

Comment: Most important takeaway: learn to use Inspect Element to see exactly what CSS is being applied to any element; makes questions like this really trivial.

Comment: I was just going through the bootstrap css file and realised it's exactly what you said and you get there before.. Thanks for pointing it out I appreciate it. This is what I wrote in my css `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
     background: #fff;
     color: #000;
 }` you can update your answer and ill accept it so others can benefit from it too

Comment: Thanks for all your help and support bud, it's much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if Tamil's snippet doesn't work:

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

Like the other posters are saying it would be a lot easier to help if you posted the CSS the dropdown is already inheriting.

Comment: I've added a code pen with the css in there too and you snippet adds colour to the dropdown items and not the `Training Group` `li` when it's opened